# Wordpress faz download da pagina e não exibe

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess

Boa tarde!
Estou com o seguinte problema, algumas paginas no painel de controle do WP são baixadas ao invés de carregar normalmente quado tento acessar elas. Isso aconteceu após eu editar o .htaccess, já restaurei o mesmo e nada de resolver isso.

Segue exemplo do que está acontecendo:

Quando clico em Adicionar post a pagina não carrega mas baixa um arquivo chamado Edit.php.

.htaccess:

```
BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
END WordPress
```

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: Chegou a reiniciar o apache depois da alteração?

Comment: Não, tenho que entrar em contato com o administrador do meu site.

Comment: Pois faça isso, normalmente reiniciando normaliza.

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver com o .httaccess...  Vai em atualizações, manda reinstalar o wordpress, vê se volta. E aproveita adicione o plugin Wordfence.... Me diga se deu certo...